# Trouble using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm currently working on writing a test runner in Python 3.5.2 and implementing multiprocessing for parallel test execution. This is the first time I'm really using any kind of multi processing and running in to issues getting it to work right.

If you look below at the `run` method you can see I'm using `mp.Pool` and `pool.map` to run my tests through `self._run_spec`. This actually works pretty well. The problem I'm facing is that `self._run_spec` receives copies of the plugins not the actual instances. This leaves the original plugin instances unchanged.

I know this is a limitation based on how processes work but unsure how to change my implementation to fix this.

```
import sys
from typing import cast, List, Dict, Any
from seleniumspec.spec import Spec, SpecContext
import traceback
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
from seleniumspec.plugin import *


class Runner(object):
    specs = []
    run_specs = []
    plugins = cast(List[Plugin], [])

    def add_specs(self, specs: List[Spec]):
        [self.add_spec(spec) for spec in specs]

    def add_spec(self, spec: Spec):
        self.specs.append(spec)
        for param in spec.params:
            self.run_specs.append({'spec': spec, 'param': param})

    def add_plugins(self, plugins: List[Plugin]):
        [self.add_plugin(plugin) for plugin in plugins]

    def add_plugin(self, plugin: Plugin):
        self.plugins.append(plugin)

    def run(self):
        runner_start_event = RunnerStartPluginEvent(runner=self)
        runner_stop_event = RunnerStopPluginEvent(runner=self)

        # Hook: Runner Start
        for plugin in self.plugins:
            plugin.runner_start(runner_start_event)

        # Run Tests in Parallel
        p = mp.Pool(2)
        p.map(partial(self._run_spec, plugins=self.plugins), self.run_specs)

        # Hook: Runner Stop
        for plugin in self.plugins:
            plugin.runner_stop(runner_stop_event)

    @staticmethod
    def _run_spec(run_spec, plugins=None):
        spec = run_spec['spec']
        param = run_spec['param']
        spec_context = SpecContext()
        spec_context.param = param

        spec_start_event = SpecStartPluginEvent(spec=spec, context=spec_context)
        spec_stop_event = SpecStopPluginEvent(spec=spec, context=spec_context)
        spec_fail_event = SpecFailPluginEvent(spec=spec, context=spec_context)

        # Hook: Spec Start
        for plugin in plugins:
            plugin.spec_start(spec_start_event)

        # Hook: Spec Setup
        for spec_hook in spec.setup_hooks:
            spec_hook(context=spec_context)

        for i, step in enumerate(spec.steps):
            step_start_event = StepStartPluginEvent(step=step)
            step_stop_event = StepStopPluginEvent(step=step)

            try:
                # Hook: Step Start
                for plugin in plugins:
                    plugin.step_start(step_start_event)

                try:
                    step.fn(context=spec_context)
                except AssertionError as e:
                    raise

                # Hook: Step Stop
                for plugin in plugins:
                    plugin.step_stop(step_stop_event)
            except AssertionError as e:
                error = traceback.format_exc()
                spec_fail_event.error = error

                # Hook: Spec Fail
                for plugin in plugins:
                    plugin.spec_fail(spec_fail_event)

                break

        # Hook: Spec Teardown
        for spec_hook in spec.teardown_hooks:
            spec_hook(context=spec_context)

        # Hook: Spec Stop
        for plugin in plugins:
            plugin.spec_stop(spec_stop_event)

        return True
```

Comment: Any particular reason why using `multiprocessing` and not `multithreading`?

Comment: No honestly. This is my first time doing multiprocess/threading and used multiprocessing because that's what I saw recommended.

Comment: MultiProcess is encourage for diverse things, mostly because in Python2 the MultiThreading doesn't use all the cores, but with threads you will use the same "memory space" and will share the instances and not copies of it and in Python3 the core's issue were solved. Give it a look and if you think it will fit, I can extend this as an proper answer.

Comment: Python 3 still suffers from the GIL. Threads in CPython cannot leverage multicores at all. You use Threads when your type of work is IO bound, Processes otherwise.